# Python SKIMAGE Exposure rescale_intensity Colorbar

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, scikit-image, colorbar

I am currently processing a low contrast image in Python, using the rescale_intensity function under the SciKit Image module.

I increase the contrast on the interesting (and relatively small) data range by specifying the second and 98th percentiles of the data set:

```
p1, p2 = np.percentile(im, (2, 98))
```

and define the new, contrasted image:

```
im2 = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(im, in_range = (p1, p2))
```

This works just as expected, but when I display the colorbar, the data is shifted to the range [-1, 1]. Any way I can rescale the colorbar accordingly?

Comment: Would you mind giving us a small snippet of code that illustrates your problem, preferably with data, so that we can try and reproduce?

Comment: Never mind folks, I've solved the issue. One just has to apply the same scaling to the array before plotting. As one has two reference points defined by the percentiles, this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You are considering only the in_range of the image. The exposure.rescale_intensity function has also a out_range option which you define the value range of the output.